# How can't I type colon (:) when inside cssh (cluster ssh administration tool)?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cloud

I'm using `cssh` for firing a series of commands to a number of virtual machines at the same time. It works fine almost all the time.

However, for whatever reason it is... if I have to type "http:" for example, the colon (:) is not sent to the virtual machines. I have to resort of typing the colon into each of the individual screens attached to every virtual machine. This defeats the purpose of cssh in case I have to type lots of URLs.

I've noticed that the same happens with less than sign (<).

I've noticed that `cssh` looks like an X app squeezing into a modern KDE5 Plasma desktop. So, I suppose that it must be some sort of terminal configuration mismatch, but I'm not sure. I had this sort of trouble years ago but I can't remember how I managed to circumvent it.

Any idea how this trouble can be circumvented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just discovered that my keyboard settings are "colliding against" `cssh`. If I reset my beloved keyboard configurations to the default en_gb thing, `cssh` gets back to "normal".

In more detail, I'm using a custom keyboard configuration which I've made public under [CarpalX](http://github.com/frgomes/carpalx). This keyboard configuration is particularly good when I'm using Emacs but demonstrated to cause problems with `cssh`. I've observed that `Shift-I` for example is being misunderstood with `CapsLock-I` which under my settings translates to `UpArrow`.

It's not clear at this point what I've done wrong, since only `cssh` misbehaves with my keyboard settings, whilst everything else works just fine. I'm assuming that I've done something wrong, but it's not really clear to me at this point what is the root cause of `Shift` being confused with `CapsLock`.